# How do I add content from other site collections?

Tags: 2013, design

Trying to wrap my head around organizing a sharepoint infrastructure. I was going to do a Site Collection for each division. But, lets say I have the MIS division which has a helpdesk issue tracker app. Everyone in the company needs access to that app to log tech support issues. How can I add an app from one site collection to another site collection? Maybe I'm conceptualizing this wrong? There's a lot of information out there, but I'm having trouble making sense of how one would build a sharepoint intranet which conforms to an organization departmental structure. I know this question is a bit open ended, but I was hoping someone could at least help point me in the right direction.

Edit: I was thinking about this and I realized I could give every dept an issue tracker app and then put links to all of those apps on like a "help desk" page for the support guys.

Comment: So you mean each department will have it's own instance of Issue Tracker right and they won't share any data between them? If yes, than you are thinking in right direction.. Just build a separate app or solution and activate the app or required features in every department that needs it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to go is to deploy the app to the Help Desk site collection, grant contribute access to the greater audience to this app only and link all the site collections up to the app sitting under the Help Desk site collection. That way you have a central data source and less trouble maintaining it as your app is in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone in the company needs access to the helpdesk issue tracker app. The question here is how do you organize the access rights. To generalize, you could perhaps organize the application and/or documents and other contents by the nature of user groups and their access rights, instead of by "department". For example, say if every department has a Team Assistant role, and the TAs would have to use a resource management app, no matter it's for travel arrangement or meeting rooms. You may want to organize such apps in a central service site alone with the helpdesk one.

The apps can be then published as a link to other site collections.